# lodash javascript array of duplicates that match multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array, to simplify lets say persons with first, last, and age. I want to make a new array of all persons that have the same first name, same last name and same age. For example my starting array:

```
[
  {id: 1, first: 'fred', last: 'smith', age: 21},
  {id: 2, first: 'fred', last: 'smith', age: 21},
  {id: 3, first: 'tom', last: 'smith', age: 21},
  {id: 4, first: 'fred', last: 'smith', age: 32}
]
```

I would like to return the duplicates that match first/last/age:

```
[
  {id: 1, first: 'fred', last: 'smith', age: 21},
  {id: 2, first: 'fred', last: 'smith', age: 21}
]
```

I'm struggling with _.uniq to figure out how to do this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would `.reduce()` do what you want? Compare each item with the previous, and if they match, return the later?

Comment: What happens if there are 2 freds and 2 toms? What do you expect in return?

Comment: @ Felipe Skinner, if there are 2 freds with the same last name and age, they should be included, if there are 2 toms with same last name and age, they should also be included, basically all records that match on all three criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `_.groupBy()` to group values, make sure that it is grouped by values that you determine to be the criteria for a duplicate. You can then `_.filter()` each grouped values by the lengths of the arrays they accumulated and then `_.flatten()` it to obtain the final array.

```js
var data = [
  {id: 1, first: 'fred', last: 'smith', age: 21},
  {id: 2, first: 'fred', last: 'smith', age: 21},
  {id: 3, first: 'tom', last: 'smith', age: 21},
  {id: 4, first: 'fred', last: 'smith', age: 32}
];

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy(i => _(i).pick('first', 'last', 'age').values().value())
  .filter(i => i.length > 1)
  .flatten()
  .value();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me you the multi-property form of `pick`.